# Need little changes in my code (java)(count lines)(beginner)

Tags: java, file

My target is to write a code which allow me to calculate number of lines in txt files from folder and his subfolders, i wrote a code which allows me to do it only for a single file, what should i change to get good result? Directory cant be specified in code.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Lines {


    public static String getValueFromUser(String comment) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println(comment);
        return scanner.nextLine();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String filePath = getValueFromUser("location: ");
        readFileContent(filePath);
    }

    private static void readFileContent(String filePath) {
        int numberOfLines = 0;
        String textLine;

        try (BufferedReader fileReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filePath))) {
            while ((textLine = fileReader.readLine()) != null) {
                numberOfLines++;
            }
            System.out.println("number of lines: " + numberOfLines);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            System.out.println("no file found.");
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you allowed to use the `Files` class? If so, have a look at `Files.walk()` (streams all file paths) or `Files.find()` (applies a filter early in the stream).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To count all lines of all .txt files in a directory you'd need to iterate over the content of that directory and its subdirectories. Using the `Files` class this is quite easy (if you're allowed to do so):

```
Files.walk(Path.of(filePath )) //iterates through all files and directories in the given locaction
     .filter(path -> Files.isRegularFile(path)) //we're only interested in files
     .filter(path -> path.toFile().getName().endsWith(".txt")) //specifically those ending in .txt
     .forEach(path -> readFileContent(path.toString())); //call your method here
```

Note that this will just print the number of lines for each file. If you need to get a total you should not use `forEach()` but `maptoInt(...).sum()` and return the number of lines from your method.

Comment: ok, forEach method works, but mapToInt doesnt, i changeg readFileContent to int, added return statement, but now result of that sum is ignored.

Comment: @user15787568 assuming you're returning `numberOfLines` correctly, did you use something like `mapToInt(path -> readFileContent(path.toString()))`? Also note that this will result in an `IntStream` so you need a `sum()` in the end - and of course store the result of that method somewhere and print it.